# Audience Manager Contact Login issue

Tags: audience-manager

I am able to register and sync the contact using Audience Manager APIS in Tridion 2013 SP1.
But I am not able to login via this user.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Where did you create the Contact - on the website or in Tridion CME? Are you certain that the Contact has been synchronized (do you see it in the subscription database used by the website)? Did you use the sample Extended Details and sample subscription web pages, or did you create your own? etc.

Comment: Created a user on CDA, I am able to see this user in Audience Manager at CMS. I have created my own Subscription page for creating a user

Comment: Did you specify an Address Book for the Contact, or did it end up in (Unassigned Contacts)?

Comment: Its in assigned AB (Global --custom AB)

Comment: And that Address Book is synchronized to the CD database? Did you check if the Contact is in the submngt database after the synchronization?

Comment: its in CMS AB DB but not in Subscription DB. Howcome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if the Address Book isn't set to be synchronized to the subscription database.

Make sure you add the Address Book to the "Audience Management" tab of a Publication which uses the right Synchronization Target. Also make sure that the "Synchronize Address Book" checkbox is checked (and thus the "Synchronized" list column says "Yes" next to the Address Book).

Comment: thanks a lot. Its working now. This was the missing step :) thanks again